# How to get multiImagePicker2 Asset object from File object in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, file, dart, assets

To get images from phone gallery,, Using MultiImagePicker2 package *https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker2*

you get The Images in Object of type `Asset`,, then you usually transform the ByteData into a `File` to use it around ,, using the below method,, you get File from Asset.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:bldrs/controllers/drafters/text_manipulators.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker2/multi_image_picker2.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> getFileFromAsset(Asset asset) async {
ByteData _byteData = await asset.getThumbByteData(asset.originalWidth, asset.originalHeight, quality: 100);

String _name = TextMod.trimTextAfterLastSpecialCharacter(asset.name, '.');

print('asset name is : ${asset.runtimeType}');

final _tempFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${_name}');
await _tempFile.writeAsBytes(_byteData.buffer.asUint8List(_byteData.offsetInBytes, _byteData.lengthInBytes));
await _tempFile.create(recursive: true);

File _file = _tempFile;

return _file;
}
```

so my question is..
**Can you reverse this method,, to get `Asset`  from `File` instead ?**